# Xcode Server Bot removing "Unknown Team" Certificates

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, xcode-server, xcode-bots

I am trying to delete these "Unknown Team" entries, from my Xcode Server but I am unable to figure out where they are. They don't seem to be in my local key chain and they don't seem to be in my remote keychain. Yet they keep showing up. I tried restarting Xcode Server, and right clicking on the "Unknown Team" entry "Remove Certificate from Remote Server" is grayed out. Anyone know where they are so I can manually go delete them?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did resolve this, and just to document it, although not very well. I believe it involved clearing the caches in the `/Library/Developer/XcodeServer/`folder, I am sorry don't know which things to clear out but I hope this helps someone narrow it down and can update the answer with something more helpful.